# Bash script to SSH to a server and connect to DB

Tags: mysql, bash, ssh

I want to test connectivity to DBs via a shell script that will SSH on to a number of boxes and then test the mysql connection. I have SSH keys working so I am not explicitly specifying user@server in the ssh command. The script is not working as i would expect and prompts me for a password but errors and uses the password as a DB name. Can some one please advise?

```
#!/bin/bash

SERVER_LIST=(172.10.1.1 172.10.1.2 172.10.1.3)
CONNECTION=172.0.0.10
USER="username"
PASS="password"

echo "Testing connectivity... "
for SERVER in ${SERVER_LIST[@]}
do
    echo "SSHing to $SERVER"
    ssh $SERVER "mysql -h $CONNECTION -u $USER -p$PASS"
done
echo "Finished."
```

After some reading around, should i have a expects command or similar on the password prompt? I have experimented with this to no avail...

Comment: Did your password have specials characters ? Can you show us what you get when you execute script ?

Comment: Sure thing

Enter password: password
ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'password'

Comment: First of all, try your mysql command outside of your bash script and outside of ssh. Then test it with the ssh command and then with the bash script. If you don't use root user, I think you have to specify a db name.

Answer (score 1):

You must export you public key to authorized_keys in your .ssh folder in the server

1. Generate your keys

   `ssh-keygen -t rsa`
2. Create .ssh on the server if it doesn't exists
   `ssh b@B mkdir -p .ssh`
3. Send them to the server

   `cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh b@B 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'`
4. Test your login

   `ssh b@B`

If anything goes wrong use `ssh -v b@B` to figure it out

Comment: sorry, i should have mentioned that I have ssh keys to establish the SSH connection, the ssh connection is not the concern as far as I can see as I am able to get onto the boxes, it is the mysql connection that is the issue

Answer (score 1):

```
Enter password: password ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'password'
```

From the error message, the `mysql` client erroneously understand *password* as the DB name. And if it asks for the password, that means it receive the `-p` option *without* a password. So, all behave like if the client has received the command `mysql .... -p password` (notice the *space* after `p`).

My guess is there is somehow a *space* before the password somewhere. Maybe in the following line:

```
PASS="password"
```

If you copied-pasted that password, maybe there is an *invisible* character before ([zero-width space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space)?). Try to remove, then hand-write that line.

In addition, try proper quoting (not *that* proper: this won't work if any of your variables holds a `'`). At the very least, this might help to narrow the problem:

```
ssh "$SERVER" "mysql -h '$CONNECTION' -u '$USER' -p'$PASS'"
```

Comment: I'm agree with you that's what I asked for special characters in `password`.

Comment: @kranteg Yes, I've up-voted your comment about that yesterday. I would point out that some "special characters" might indeed be "unintentional" and "invisible". I've already have that kind of issue with users having copied-pasted their login/password from their _webmail_. For formating purpose, some invisible characters where added and sneaked in with the original text as the user copied it from his browser. This is highly speculative though. And without further feedback of the OP, I think we're stuck from now.